# Dropbox folder not created although installed dropbox in 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, dropbox

I can launch dropbox from dash that open the web interface and shows that it connects with my computer. But, in my home directory there is no dropbox folder.

Comment: How did you install Dropbox? Did you install the `nautilus-dropbox' package?

Comment: @pomsky Yes, I also install this package.